# Website spam hidden in banner

Tags: html, spam

We have got this website: [AIESEC](http://aiesec.org.mx) if you go to the bottom of the page you will see a kind of slideshow that changes from time to time:

[image]

What I have found is that when you put your mouse over that banner it shows a series of spam pages. So I decided to take a look into the a code and imagined it was a div that contained a group of images that then they had an a href tag and so on... But my surprise is that for that banner I found the following spam code:

```
<div style="position:absolute;filter:alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0.001;z-index:10;"> <a href="http://www.segwayofhershey.com/"><b>uggs black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.mafrancegourmet.com/"><b>north face cyber monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.wastefwd.com/"><b>lululemon black friday</b></a> <a href="http://merkleinsurance.com/"><b>michael kors black Friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.greentreepartners.com/"><b>uggs black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.greenfieldfirstbaptist.com/"><b>uggs cyber monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.wilmingtonbands.org/"><b>Longchamp black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.casinoparties.com/"><b>louis vuitton cyber Monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.brookwoodtownhouses.com/"><b>north face black friday sale</b></a> <a href="http://www.spanish411.net/"><b>uggs cyber monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.southalabamafilmfestival.org/"><b>michael kors cyber Monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.ryanmoving.com/"><b>polo black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.tri-state-k9.org/"><b>kate spade black friday</b></a> <a href="http://pdcpubliclibrary.org/"><b>Miumiu black Friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.iztechnologies.com/"><b>michael kors black Friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.hauswiesner.com/"><b>abercrombie and fitch black Friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.vietventures.com/"><b>black Friday beats by dre</b></a> <a href="http://www.waltspetro.com/"><b>under armour black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.artisanvoice.com/"><b>the north face cyber monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.exterapartners.com/"><b>north face cyber monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.ahrunsfamousinc.com/"><b>nike black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.wilmheadstart.org/"><b>canada goose cyber monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.pic-nicc.org/"><b>uggs black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.raneytruss.com/"><b>beats by dre cyber Monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.nhaccounting.net/"><b>uggs black friday</b></a> <a href="http://jennchase.com/"><b>north face black friday</b></a> <a href="http://prescottrepairs.com"><b>uggs black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.virtualarmory.com/"><b>chanel cyber monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.warfieldpointpark.com/"><b>beats by dre cyber Monday</b></a> <a href="http://elkhartmunicipalband.com/"><b>north face black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.mscasati.com/"><b>tod's black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.vietventures.com/"><b>beats by dre cyber Monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.ahavastorah.info/"><b>north face cyber monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.walaser.com/"><b>lululemon cyber monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.ranchwise.com/"><b>kate spade cyber monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.janeadenymemorialschool.com/"><b>michael kors cyber Monday</b></a> <a href="http://www.newenergyfarms.com/"><b>christian louboutin black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.sagamusic.com"><b>uggs black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.mashinsky.com/"><b>north face black friday</b></a> <a href="http://www.intersoftconcepts.com/"><b>true religion cyber monday</b></a></div></body>
```

So if you take a look it does not make any sense because it does not contain any image, just links to external pages that are total spam.

I have erased all what is inside the div tag just like this:

```
 <div style="position:absolute;filter:alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0.001;z-index:10;"> </div></body>
```

but then the banner dissapears.

Some users had told me that whenever they visit our website they get an antivirus alert from that webpage.

What do you think is going on?
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with the website got hacked?

Comment: Do you actually want the banner underneath (without the links, obviously)? It is simply the background peeking through and the height of the div is determined by the number of links. For example, if you leave one link, then the gap will be one line high.

Comment: Yeah. We just want the group of images to be changing. We do not want the spam, indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove the spam links and give height to the div. remove the `position:absolute` too.

`<div style="opacity: 0.001; z-index: 10; height: 250px;"> </div>`

Comment: Glad it helped. It would be great if you accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The space is currently created by the invisible links themselves pushing the div down 196 pixels. This simply creates white space underneath the container so the background image can be seen.

#### To keep the same look without the spam div

- Remove the spammy div completely
- You can keep the gap by placing an appropriate bottom margin on the existing `.container` div (`margin-bottom: 196px` to keep the same gap).

  ```
  .container { 
      margin-bottom: 192px; 
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Gonna test this. I will have to create a container right? I don't have any just this spammy div

Comment: There is already a wrapping div with the class `container` that you can apply the margin to, it looks like this: `<div class="container">
            <header class="row">
                <!-- Navigation Bar -->`

Comment: So you meant like this: <div class="container"; margin-bottom: 196px> <header class="row"> <!-- Navigation Bar --> ?

Comment: Do you have access to the CSS? If you do, then you can just add `.container { margin-bottom: 192px; }` at the bottom of it. If you don't, then you would place the CSS inline like this: `<div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 196px">`

Comment: Already did it. I will have to play then with the pixels because this margin is too much. Thanks!

Comment: @MikePérez - You can create a bottom margin on `.container` of whatever size you want. No need to keep that spam div.